# How to connect Oracle MCS with EBS?

Tags: oracle, oracle-maf, mcs

I need to connect Oracle MCS with EBS. what are the procedures for establishing the connection between Oracle MCS and Oracle EBS. If anybody knows please help me.

1. Need to get some data from already existed table in EBS.
2. Tried to create a SOAP connector in MCS and give the WSDL url. But got an error while creating.

   Error is: *WSDL Validation:[WSDL URL] : MOBILE-61507: Redirector call failed. - Unable to complete call from the redirector to environment tooling component : com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out.*

Thanks,
JKJ

Comment: have you done some research before asking?

Answer (score 2):

1. Expose your things on the EBS side using a web service (ex: [click](https://redstack.wordpress.com/2010/05/20/exposing-e-business-suite-services-using-the-integrated-soa-gateway/))
2. Add an [SOAP](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/mobilecs_gs/MCSUA/GUID-A5CCD158-4977-4051-A8D8-5E2BECB2B6A8.htm#MCSUA-GUID-A5CCD158-4977-4051-A8D8-5E2BECB2B6A8) or [REST](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/mobilecs_gs/MCSUA/GUID-12D976D7-5FCA-49C1-8D85-44A9BC438254.htm#MCSUA-GUID-12D976D7-5FCA-49C1-8D85-44A9BC438254) connection on the MCS side
3. Develop a Custom API (ex: [click](http://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/mobilecs_gs/MCSUA/GUID-FC462111-E249-4918-8652-21755E23A6C1.htm#MCSUA-GUID-FC462111-E249-4918-8652-21755E23A6C1))
4. Consume that Custom API in your mobile app (ex: [click](https://blogs.oracle.com/mobile/entry/maf_mcs_utility_accessing_oracle))

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind response. Now i am able to access EBS from MCS connector. I have done the following steps:

1. Created a REST Connector in MCS and give corresponding EBS api URL.
2. Give corresponding header and body parameter.
3. By pressing "Test Endpoint" button, the response will generated and status code 200 is return.

Thanks,

JKJ

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?